# What is the rationale not to use ArrayList in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, collections, arraylist

I have come across this code snippet in a source code

```
#if SILVERLIGHT
        internal static System.Collections.IList CreateArrayList()
        {
            return new List<object>();
        }

#else
        internal static System.Collections.IList CreateArrayList()
        {
            return new ArrayList();
        }

#endif
```

What might be the purpose of this different treatment?

Comment: I would probably ask - "Why not use List<T> in non-Silverlight?"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Silverlight doesn't have the deprecated non-generic collection classes; they are not merely discouraged; they're not there at all.

What is bizarre about that code is: clearly it works for the SilverLight case, so *why leave the old code in at all*?  There's no compelling benefit to using the ArrayList, is there?

Comment: Unless you're also building for .NET 1.1 or the micro-framework, of course.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Good point. But that seems also bizarre; if that's the case then why special-case SilverLight?  Why isn't the code "#if DOTNET_V1_1", so that the ArrayList is only used if it *has* to be used?

Comment: one possible explanation is perhaps the project started with the old code, and when they found out that it didn't work with Silverlight, they decided to make a special case for it, and they don't know (or don't bother to find out) about which versions can't use the generic List, so they leave the code that way.

Comment: I also find that new C# programmers who come from other languages (e.g., Pascal/Delphi in my case) search for `dynamic array` and encounter ArrayList: http://img200.imageshack.us/img200/2812/screenshot20111010at148.png - Good that the #1 result is a SO Answer also mentioning `List<T>`, but ArrayList is still THE google result for dynamic arrays.